# Geocoding with Google and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm new to jquery but I am having a bit of a hard time at the moment. This is as far as I can get, the eventual idea is to do the following:

1. User types in an address and clicks search
2. Google Geocoder runs
3. Either error if not result, or grab co-ordinates, state, zip, country, city and print in a message box

The code I have at the moment is not even able to complete the process of grabbing the coordinates from the input box. It keeps telling me it is expecting a bracket but no matter where I put the bracket I cannot get it to run.

This is my trying to run:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/QA7Xr/16/
```

Here is the complete code:

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(31.272410, 0.190898);


// INITALIZATION
 function initialize() {
     var mapOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
 }


// GEOCODE
  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert("Geocode was successful");
        };
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      };
    };
  }


// GET ADDRESS DETAILS
 function getLatLongDetail() {
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({
         'latLng': myLatlng
     },
     function (results, status) {
         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             if (results[0]) {
                 var address = "",
                     city = "",
                     state = "",
                     zip = "",
                     country = "";
                 for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                     var addr = results[0].address_components[i];
                     // check if this entry in address_components has a type of country
                     if (addr.types[0] == 'country') country = addr.long_name;
                     else if (addr.types[0] == 'street_address') // address 1
                     address = address + addr.long_name;
                     else if (addr.types[0] == 'establishment') address = address + addr.long_name;
                     else if (addr.types[0] == 'route') // address 2
                     address = address + addr.long_name;
                     else if (addr.types[0] == 'postal_code') // Zip
                     zip = addr.short_name;
                     else if (addr.types[0] == ['administrative_area_level_1']) // State
                     state = addr.long_name;
                     else if (addr.types[0] == ['locality']) // City
                     city = addr.long_name;
                 }
                 alert('City: ' + city + '\n' + 'State: ' + state + '\n' + 'Zip: ' + zip + '\n' + 'Country: ' + country);
             }
         }
     });
 }

 initialize();
 getLatLongDetail();
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please? I've hit a dead end with this.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the error that is logged in the console? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { fiddle.jshell.net:44

Comment: Correcting your fiddle. Bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS was a mess, I've tidied it up: http://jsfiddle.net/QA7Xr/19/

In order:

- Two extra close brackets in a function
- You used `getElementById()` using an ID that did not exist
- You bound an onClick when a JS assignment is easier
- Your `geocoder` var was local within getLatLongDetail. You needed it in codeAddress, so I've made it global.

Points to improve:

- Wrap your code in a closure to avoid namespace pollution
- Use the Google events to control your code assignments. Right now, if a user clicks too quickly, your code will throw up
- Simplify the logic

Comment: P.S: Google thinks I'm in Algeria. I'm not using a proxy. WIN!

Comment: @Xotic750: Wrong. The JS error is from jsFiddle, not from his code.

Comment: You made a good start on something that was a mess, but it is still far from correct.

Comment: @Xotic750: OP's question was "it won't run", not "make it for me". I have pointed him in the right direction to improve his current code in addition to actually making it run. What are you picking fault on? He **never** said "Write my code", merely "fix my code".

Comment: (Also, if I wanted to, I could write it in a three-liner before minification. Would he understand it? No.)

Comment: Ok, so I tell you that it is much better, and you did a good job at an initial cleanup so that it actually displays something. I point out that the code is far from perfect, which backs up the fact that you have also stated there are things to improve, or more precisely fix. But hey, whatever,.

Comment: @Xotic750: "but still much that is not good" was overly vague. As for the rest...misunderstanding? Side note - could the downvoter actually say *why* they downvoted?

Comment: This perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500222/google-geocoding-cannot-pull-co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated link,

http://jsfiddle.net/QA7Xr/24/

```
geocoder.geocode({}, function(){....}); /*not closed properly*/
```

and there are improper usage of semicolon.